# .NET MAUI - crop camera image

Tags: ios, xamarin, maui

Currently working on a feature where I want to crop an image taken from camera in iOS (Android already working)

Currently referred to the library
https://github.com/jbowmanp1107/ImageCropper.Maui
I have raised an issue
https://github.com/jbowmanp1107/ImageCropper.Maui/issues/7

*Below Error Showing in file 'PlatformImageCropper.cs'*
An error occurred: 'Could not create an native instance of the type 'Bind_TOCropViewController.TOCropViewController': the native class hasn't been loaded.

I have also tried implementing 'MediaPlugin' - Xamarin Library
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin
and i was able to run project in android but in iOS it crashes and feature is only available for iOS
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#allow-cropping

Can anyone please help on this feature would be great!!!

Comment: What do you expect as answer? Some library written by some guy named "Jeff Bowman", that uses some controls by some other guy "Tim Oliver", is not working. Making such libraries work, requires you to understand what they are doing, and fixing them does not require less time than writing your own. Also, tomorrow when one of the authors decide he will be alpaca wool dealer, instead of programmer, what will you do? When next Android/IOS comes, do you think you will get updates in time? I advise against using such libs, for anything but school projects.

Comment: As an answer I expected someone from the community who would have faced the similar issue
And that they would have implemented a feature in a different way other than the ways I tried.
Helping and encouraging would be appreciate rather than you taking out time to criticise and question some author’s work.

Comment: Samy, I do not know what is the answer of your problem. But I am sharing my experience to tell you that this what you are doing, is not the right path. Do not take this as critic, take it as warning. One day such libs get out of service, and this happens usually at the worst time possible. If this is commercial project you are working on, you should avoid it at all cost. This is my point of view, feel free to completely ignore me.

Comment: Thanks H.A.H, I see your POV and from your experience the problems/issues with projects that you have dealt with could possibly be same for me in a commercial projects. I take this as a guidance now. No worries with the answers, will surely get it working somehow. Thanks Mate.

Answer (score 1):

The image in Maui has a Clip property, you can set different shapes to it to achieve the effect you want to crop. For example:

```
//create circular area
var clip = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(100, 100), 100, 100);
// create a rectangular area
var clip1 = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(100,100,100,100));
image. Clip = clip1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Dongzhi Wang-MSFT,  cropping was needed on camera click but will check this code in Ui for the app

Comment: Do you want to crop while taking a photo?

Comment: Yes, i have it working now with the same nuget package that i referred above. if there's any alternative then that will be also helpful

Comment: @SamyGray, ca you share us how do you make it working? My code failed at the init itself

Comment: @Fitri Halim the issue is with .MAUI's iOS development in Windows PC. For me running the app in MAC's Visual Studio helped and we concluded that there are few or more things that run properly in MAC's Visual Studio rather than Window's Visual Studio for iOS app Development [note: you can only install the app in iphone through Window's Visual Studio and not debug it]

Comment: Hi @SamyGray - i am facing the same issue but on a Mac Visual Studio - was there any other change that you made? It is failing when creating a new ImageCropper on my MainPage. The Init seems to be fine